# PHP replace string starting with xxx and ending with yyy after 5 characters

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

Input:

```
$str = 'hi test1="12c4 ab3d" blablabla test1="5678 sdfg"'
```

So I need to remove string between 'test1="' and '"' after 5 characters, like that:

```
'hi test1="12c4" blablabla test1="5678"'
```

I already tried:

```
$str= preg_replace('/test1="[\s\S]+?"/', 'test1=""', $str);
```

But my ouput was:

```
'hi test1="" blablabla test1=""'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
$str = 'hi test1="12c4 ab3d" blablabla test1="abcd 3456 sdfs 2435"';
echo preg_replace('~\btest1="[^"\s]*\K[^"]+~', '', $str);
// => hi test1="12c4" blablabla test1="abcd"
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MnZfY) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a3E6Vy/4).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `test1="` - a literal text
- `[^"\s]*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace and `"`
- `\K` - match reset operator that removes the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `[^"]+` - one or more chars other than `"`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What if test1 is longer? like test1="abcd 3456 sdfs 2435"

Comment: @user16405471 I adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, without a regex and using simple `strpos()` and `substr()`

```
$str = 'hi test1="12c4 ab3d" blablabla test1="5678 sdfg"';

$find = 'test1=';
$p1 = stripos($str, $find) + strlen($find)+5;
$p2 = strripos($str, $find) + strlen($find)+5;

$new =  substr($str, 0, $p1) . substr($str, $p1+5, $p2-$p1-5) . substr($str, $p2+5);
echo $new . PHP_EOL;
```